# How to pass my data from javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

I  have a JS that I send coordinates from that into a Servlet.

In my JS I get coordinates from a jsp page like this:

```
 function main1() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ServeltConnection',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
       latitude: pos.lat,
       longitude: pos.lng,

     },
    success: function(data){

    //call of  functions
    }
});
}
```

I need these coordinates so as to send them into my servlet for getting a return into a json format.

In my Servlet:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter(), true);
    List<Shop> shops;

    try{

    //code for connection with database
            shops=getShops(request.getParameter("latitude"),request.getParameter("longitude"));

        String json = new Gson().toJson(shops);
        response.getWriter().write(shops);
        db.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
  out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
```

When I give specific coordinates in latitude and longitude I GET my json right, but when I' m trying to get coordinates from the js it's not working. I think that the wrong is the way I parse longitude and latitude from js..I searched for parsing JSON but I can't do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean "pass" your data to the servlet

Comment: yes that i meant, sorry!!

Comment: I want to take the coordinates in which I am right now, and put markings on the map in the nearest shops. But it seems that servlet doesnt get the coordinates in shops=getShops(request.getParameter("latitude"),request.getParameter("longitude"));

Answer (score 1):

You must put parameters of GET requests on the url, like this way:

```
url: 'ServeltConnection?latitude="+pos.lat+"&longitude="+pos.lng+"'
```

As well don't forget to remove the `'data'` parameter